# passing parameters to python decorator

Tags: python, decorator, uwsgi

I am using uwsgi decorators(specifically the cron decorator) to do things at specific times. I have the following code:

```
import cherrypy
import uwsgidecorators

class TestObject(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        launchapp = self.launchapp(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"foobar")
        return "This is a test"

    @uwsgidecorators.cron(minute,hour,day,month,dayweek)
    def launchapp(self,target):
        print "the target is %s" %target
        return
```

However I get the error:

```
    @uwsgidecorators.cron(minute,hour,day,month,dayweek)
NameError: name 'minute' is not defined
```

I am basically trying to specify the timing parameters for the cron decorator in the index function. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like you defined a value for `minute` so that's not surprising.  You are just doing a function call so you need to pass in some value for that argument.

Comment: do you mean like `launchapp = self.launchapp(minute = -1,hour = -1,day = -1,month = -1,dayweek = -1,target = "foobar")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why your code fails

The error has nothing to do with the fact that you're passing parameters, it's just that the `minute` variable is undefined.

You would get the exact same error doing:

```
>>> a = 'a'
>>> print b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
>>>
```

What you probably want to do is:

```
@uwsgidecorators.cron(minute = 5,hour = 2, # and so on.
```

Please have a look at the [uwsgi documentation](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Decorators#cron) for a more comprehensive example.

---

-- EDIT below.

### How you could fix it

It seems that you're trying to add a task to your crontab after index is hit.

That's not the use case for the decorator, the decorator is only meant to say that a function should run on a cron **at function definition**. 
Basically, when the decorator is executed (and the function **defined**, not **called**), it gets added to the crontab.

In your case, you want to add a function to the crontab; so you should use something like [`uwsgi.add_cron`](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/CronInterface). You can have a look at the [decorator code](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/browser/uwsgidecorators.py#L254) to see how you could use it.

You shouldn't be using a method but a function, though.

Comment: but I am trying to pass in the parameters (the 5, 2 in your example) from the index function. I need the launchapp method to be dynamic so that I can call it multiple times from index with different timings